# Serialize multiple choice elements from XML to C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have this schema

```
<xs:complexType name="FatherElement">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="FatherClass"/>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="FatherType"/>
                <xs:element ref="FatherLocation" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="FatherTypeDescription" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="FatherLocation"/>
                <xs:element ref="FatherTypeDescription" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="FatherTypeDescription"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="FatherBasis"/>
        <xs:element ref="FatherRole" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="Extension" type="FatherElement_ExtensionType" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And I'm trying to map with this C# mapping (it would be nice to have all the fields, but I don't need them all now)

```
[System.Serializable()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.lol.com/Standards/lol/1")]
public class FatherElement
{
    /// <remarks/>
    public string FatherTypeDescription { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string FatherType { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    public FatherLocation FatherLocation { get; set; }
}


[System.Serializable()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.lol.com/Standards/lol/1")]
public class FatherLocation
{
    /// <remarks/>
    public FatherLocationLocation Location { get; set; }
}


[System.Serializable()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.lol.com/Standards/lol/1")]
public class FatherLocationLocation
{
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

The incoming XML value I get is

```
<FatherElement>
    <FatherClass>classValue</FatherClass> 
    <FatherType>typeValue</FatherType> 
    <FatherTypeDescription>typeValueDesc</FatherTypeDescription> 
    <FatherBasis>basisValue</FatherBasis> 
    <FatherRole>RoleValue</FatherRole> 
</FatherElement>
```

And the one I get out is:

```
<FatherElement>
    <FatherTypeDescription>typeValueDesc</FatherTypeDescription>
    <FatherType>typeValue</FatherType>
  </FatherElement>
```

When I try to validate it against SDC, I get an error saying that the element FatherElement has an invalid child FatherTypeDescription.

I tried to generate the C# mapping from the XSD, but the code it generates convert the choices into element of type objects and I'd like to keep the strong typing.

Any idea?

Comment: Last time I used XSDs to generate WCF classes (VS2012) the `<xs:choice>` element wasn't supported.

Comment: It is support now. When a choice element is used it creates two elements in the model an Object Item and an ItemName of type enum (where the enum contains the available fields within the choice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I got around it with extracting the mapping from the xsd.
It looks like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.lol.com/Standards/lol/1")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("FatherProvision", Namespace = "http://www.lol.com/Standards/lol/1", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class FatherElement
{

    private string FatherClassField;

    private object[] itemsField;

    private ItemsChoiceType3[] itemsElementNameField;

    private string FatherBasisField;

    private string FatherRoleField;

    private FatherProvision_ExtensionType extensionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "NMTOKEN")]
    public string FatherClass
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FatherClassField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FatherClassField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FatherAuthorityLocation", typeof(FatherAuthorityLocationType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FatherType", typeof(string), DataType = "NMTOKEN")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FatherTypeDescription", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemsChoiceType3[] ItemsElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsElementNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsElementNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "NMTOKEN")]
    public string FatherBasis
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FatherBasisField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FatherBasisField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "NMTOKEN")]
    public string FatherRole
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FatherRoleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FatherRoleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public FatherProvision_ExtensionType Extension
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionField = value;
        }
    }
}


public enum ItemsChoiceType3
{

    /// <remarks/>
    FatherAuthorityLocation,

    /// <remarks/>
    FatherType,

    /// <remarks/>
    FatherTypeDescription,
}
```

I then access the element by first checking the index of the element of the desired type (if any) in the name element array, and then use that index to access the element.

```
var fatherTypeElement = string.Empty;
var fatherAuthorityLocationElement = (fatherAuthorityLocationType)null;
var fatherTypeElementIndex = Array.IndexOf(fatherProvisionAndPercentage.fatherProvision.ItemsElementName, ItemsChoiceType3.fatherType);
if(fatherTypeElementIndex >= 0)
    fatherTypeElement = fatherProvisionAndPercentage.fatherProvision.Items[fatherTypeElementIndex] as string;
```

Answer (score 1):

`<xs:choice>` is still a problem when generating classes. The problem is the boxing and naming of the element chosen. I'd suggest a workaround.

As I understood you want to choose between three possibilities:

1. Father has `Type` and can have `Location` and `Description`
2. Father has `Location` and can `Description`
3. Father has `Description` only

The problem is that, the sequence-types defined within your choice won't be recognized corectly (like MaPi commented, you'd have to use ItemName-Enum and Item).
You could move the coosable sequences into an eleement, to explain VS to handle them as single objects. Here an example (I did replace your complex types with strings to acchieve a comilable/generatable example):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="FatherElement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="FatherClass" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:choice> <!-- In this choice we can choose 3 different elements -->
                    <xs:element name="CompleteFather"> <!-- 1 -->
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="FatherType" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="FatherLocation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="FatherTypeDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="UncompletaFather"> <!-- 2 -->
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="FatherLocation" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="FatherTypeDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="FatherTypeDescription" type="xs:string"/> <!-- 3 -->
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here some example c#-code.

```
FatherElement e = new FatherElement();
e.FatherClass = "Some Element";

// Here we choose our element in our choice. It'll be boxed into an object.
e.Item = new FatherElementCompleteFather()
{
    FatherLocation = "loc",
    FatherType = "type",
    FatherTypeDescription = "desc"
};

string filePath = @"C:\Temp\test.xml";
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(e.GetType());

using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    x.Serialize(sw, e);
```

Comment: Thanks. The idea is good, but the main issue is that the xsd is produced by a third party, so I can't really play around with it